# How to include and use cordova plugins

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I'm struggling with **cordova plugins** in my **ionic** app. Been googling whole day, no big win yet.

here's what I'm trying to do - open a web page inside my app with navbar present. I found that [cordova-themeable](https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser) might work that out

...however...

I installed it

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser
```

ok, it's present

```
$ cordova plugin list
cordova-plugin-camera 2.2.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.0.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.3 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.2.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser 0.2.15 "ThemeableBrowser"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.0 "Keyboard"
```

now, I'm trying to use it in controller function

```
$scope.doStuff = function doStuff() {
    cordova.ThemeableBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', {
        ...
```

and call it in my *.html* file

```
<ion-item ng-click="doStuff()">
```

I get the following error

```
ReferenceError: cordova is not defined at Scope.doStuff
```

in my **index.html**, I've got

```
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

please help, thanks

Comment: Did you add cordova to your project?

Comment: @matt93 Ensure to invoke the plugin code inside ionicPlatform.ready function

Comment: @Gandhi thanks, I added it in my function:  $scope.doStuff = function doStuff() {
            ionic.Platform.ready(function () {
                cordova.ThemeableBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', { ... but still - cordova not defined in ionic lab, in emulator it does nothing. I wonder if there are some dependencies missing or maybe the way I call it in my html file is wrong??

Comment: is it even possible to use cordova.ThemeableBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', {..}); in my controller ?

Comment: @matt93 I dont have hand on experience in Ionic as i work only on vanilla cordova framework. But what i have learned is platform ready need not be added explicitly. In blank Ionic template project it will be available by default in app.js You jus got to invoke plugin code inside that

Comment: any fixes to this ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify the plugin is in your config.xml?

It should look something like this:

```
    <plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.example">
    <param name="APIKey" value="12345678" />
    <param name="APISecret" value="12345678" />
    </plugin>
```

Comment: I found  <feature name="ThemeableBrowser">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.initialxy.cordova.themeablebrowser.ThemeableBrowser" />
    </feature> in my .../platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml but nothing similar present in .../platforms/ios/appName/config.xml and there are no features in my .../appName/config.xml. please would you be more specific how to configure this? thank in an advance

Comment: update - ok, I added the plugin again with --save option and now it's in my app/config.xml: <plugin name="cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser" spec="~0.2.15" />, but still not working. neither in emulator nor simulator :/

Answer (score 0):

would have added this as a comment, but not enough rep and only posting as i cant see any mention of any of this.

make sure it is injected properly into your app, given the error or cordova not defined i'm assuming this might be an issue. i couldnt find any specifc references to it, but considering it is built on top of the inappbrowser, i would assume the DI would be $cordovaInAppBrowserProvider.

while reading the docs, from their gitgub FAQ "I just installed this plugin, how come it just shows a blank toolbar?

The purpose of this plugin is to allow you to style the in app browser the way you want. Isn't that why you installed this plugin in the first place? Hence, it does not come with any defaults. Every UI element needs to be styled by you, otherwise it's hidden. This also avoids polluting your resouce bundle with default images."

Answer (score 0):

To add a plugin you are doing right, i.e. if you want to use [cordova adomb plugin](https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/wiki/Setup):

```
cordova plugin add cordova-admob
```

Regarding to the error: Are you debugging in browser or in real device? Normally in browser, you should use

```
cordova platform add browser
phonegap serve
```

(I recommend you to use `phonegap serve` insetad of `cordova serve` as sometimes it works better, but shouldn't make the difference)

Another way to debug apps is to use [android remote debug](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging).