# how to use cordova-universal-links-plugin in a ionic+cordova+angular app?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm quite a noob with cordova and this probably has an easy solution, but I've searched the entire internet and failed to find it. I even read the plugin creation guide from cordova with no luck.

I have this ionic/cordova app and I installed this plugin https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin
with this command:

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-universal-links-plugin --save
```

BTW, I am using angular 1.6, and cordova 6.5.

Now I've followed all the instructions on the gitHub page, but when calling

```
universalLinks.subscribe(...)
```

from

```
angular.module('myModule', ['libs...'])
    .run(function($ionicPlatform, $state, $cordovaBadge) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
            /*HERE*/ universalLinks.subscribe(...) /*HERE*/
...
}
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: universalLinks is not defined
at app.js:44
at Array.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:56230)
at onPlatformReady (ionic.bundle.js:2496)
at onWindowLoad (ionic.bundle.js:2477)
```

I tried adding 'universalLinks' or 'universal-links' into the array of dependencies of the module, but then I get errors related to that (injector failed to find it)

I looked into the plugin's directory and there's a ./www/universalLinks.js file there that defined the universalLinks object, but I don't know what to do with that, I can't include it in the index.html since it's outside my app's www directory, and I think cordova should integrate it automatically anyway.

What am I doing wrong? How should I actually use this plugin?

There is a similar but unanswered question on SO: [How to include and use cordova plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37790860/how-to-include-and-use-cordova-plugins/43285531?noredirect=1#comment73639201_43285531)

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: No, I realized that you cannot use a cordova plugin in an angular app without having a proper angular wrapper for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a while since you asked this but here's the solution. You need to put `universalLinks.subscribe` inside "deviceready" event listener callback. Putting it inside `$ionicPlatform.ready` or other things didn't work but it seems `deviceready` event is working fine.
It should look something like this:

```
app.run(function () {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
        universalLinks.subscribe(null, function (eventData) {
            ...
        });
    });
});
```